# Changing SQL Column Data type to date in Excel with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, odbc

The following is the VBA code I am using to query the database. After querying the data base I would like to be able to perform a separate query on the new table I have created. I would like to do this query using TIMES in date format as the parameter. However, when excel loads the information from the database it loads the TIMES column as a text format instead of a date format. This makes querying by saying

```
 .ComandText = Array("SELECT TIMES FROM [QUERY1 WHERE TIMES BETWEEN '24-JUN-17 05:59:00' and '25-JUN-17 02:00:00' ]
```

give an error.

I know how to change the column format by opening up the query and manually changing the format I am hoping there is a way to do this in VBA

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Query1", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Odbc.Query(""dsn=Database"", ""SELECT c.IP_VALUE AS """"PRODUCT"""", c.IP_TIME as CTIMES , s.IP_TIME AS TIMES, s.IP_VALUE AS """"Weight""""#(lf)FROM """"Product"""" AS c , """"Weight"""" as s#(lf)#(lf)WHERE  c.IP_TIME between '24-JUN-17 05:59:00' AND '29-JUN-17 06:00:00'"")" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source"
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Query1" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT TIMES FROM [Query1]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Query1"

End With
```

Comment: comment not related to solution: instead of `& Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) &`  
 use `& Chr(13) & Chr(10) &`  or use the system constant `& vbCrLf &`